# How can I get the number of subscribers of a channel or group with telethon?

Tags: telegram, telethon

As the title says, how do I get this, without getting the ChatAdminRequiredError?

Answer (score 0):

In Telethon v1 you can use `GetFullChannelRequest`:

```py
channel = ...  # username, id, etc...
result = client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(channel))
print(result.full_chat.participants_count)
```

Comment: I cannot do this, if I don't have chat admin priviliges of a group or channel. I can only see the subscribers, not the list of subscribers nor nothing else.

Comment: This is the only way to get the total count of participants. If you can't use this, you can't get that count.